# AWS S3 Bucket endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a bucket and trying to use from an application and it is giving the following error:

"error: S3ServiceException:The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint."

I am using this format: s3://bucketname. I know the format is not an issue because I am able to use this format for another public bucket. I think the permissions on my bucket may be an issue but I am not sure.

Can someone pl. help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to use aws api in your application and provide it the credentials i.e key & secret to do things in S3. Any way which plate form application you are using?

Comment: it is an AWS ETL application so I dont need credentials etc. Actually I can list the buckets from my account and I can select it. But then if run the process it fails.

Comment: Whenever I see that error message it is because I'm trying to access the S3 bucket in a different region from the one it was created in. You need to make sure the endpoint you are using is the correct region endpoint for the bucket.

Comment: are you including region

Comment: plz share your command which you are running

Comment: The region was the issue. Once i include the region the error went away. thanks for your help guys.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/s3serviceexception-error.html

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help you a bit I used this command to copy mine images in bucket on S3 from linux command line. Please see I also use trailing /

//these commands are bidirectional

// . is showing current directory in which you are

// bucketname & region are mandatory

aws s3 cp . s3://bucketname/foldername/ --recursive --include "*" --region ap-southeast-1